# Alternatives to Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon

Not sure if there are other alternatives to Amazon SES...I have tried google but most I got are "Email Marketing or Campaign" services, but what I am trying to look for is something similar to Amazon SES, which just handles email sending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of alternatives for email delivery services:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com)
- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com)
- [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com)
- [Critsend](http://cirtsend.com)

And these are just five of these services off the top of my head. All of the above services should have free accounts, so kick the tires a bit and see which you like best.

(**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Happy to answer questions!)